# Factor $1/2$ in work done by spring force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, spring

My book says Spring Force = $-kx$  where k is spring constant and x is displacement from equilibrium position.

Then it says work done by spring force is $-kx^2/2$.

But I know Work Done = Force $×$ Displacement so in this case it should be $-kx^2$.

So why is it $-kx^2/2$?

Answer (score 5):

It's because here the force is not constant with displacement.  The definition of work done you should use is:
$$\text{d}W = F(x)\text{d}x$$
where $\text{d}W$ is the infinitesimal amount of work done over a displacement $\text{d}x$, and $F(x)$ is the force as a function of displacement.
To get the total work done over a distance $x$, we have to integrate:
$$W=\int_0^x(-kx')\text{d}x'=-kx^2/2$$
The simplified "Work done = Force $\times$ displacement" is only valid if $F(x)$ is constant.

Intuitively, this should make sense too - imagine trying to pull the spring a distance $A$ from displacement $x_0$, which is very close to the equilibrium position.  Now try to pull the string the same distance $A$ from $x_1$, which is far from the equilibrium position.  The amount of work you have to do is different in each case (the second example is much harder to do).  This would not be true if $W=Fx$ applied here.